# Smooth Anchor Link Scrolling Conflict

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to have smooth scrolling on anchor links

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = jQuery(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

However this conflicts with some hidden divs that I use to display information. Here is one example.

```
<div style="display:none;">
<div id="contact-email" >
[gravityform id=15 ajax=true title=false description=false tabindex=20]
</div>
</div>
```

If I use the code above the hidden divs are not displayed at all.

Is it possible to exclude the anchor links that correspond to my hidden divs - i only have a couple..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok the solution is to use:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
```

and then use

```
<a href="#comments" class="scroll">Scroll to comments</a>
```

for the anchor links that I would like to have smooth scrolling.

I am just wondering how efficient and browser compatible is this code..